# Model interpretation using timeslice method in CARET

Tags: time-series, glm, r-caret, forecasting

Suppose you want to evaluate a simple glm model to forecast an economic data series.
Consider the following code:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
data(economics)
h <- 7
myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                              initialWindow = 24*h,
                              horizon = 12,
                              fixedWindow = TRUE)

fit.glm <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert,
                    data = economics,
                    method = "glm",
                    preProc = c("center", "scale","BoxCox"),
                    trControl = myTimeControl)
```

Suppose that the covariates used into the train formula are predictions of values obtained by some other model.
This simple model gives the following results:

```
Generalized Linear Model 

574 samples
3 predictor

Pre-processing: centered (3), scaled (3), Box-Cox transformation (3) 
Resampling: Rolling Forecasting Origin Resampling (12 held-out with a fixed   
window) 
Summary of sample sizes: 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, ... 
Resampling results:

RMSE      Rsquared 
1446.335  0.2958317
```

Apart from the bad results obtained (this is only an example).
I wonder if it is correct:

1. To consider the above results as results obtained, on the entire dataset, by a GLM trained using only 24*h=24*7 samples and retrained after every horizon=12 samples
2. How evaluate RMSE as horizon grows from 1 to 12 (as reported here http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/ )?

if I show fit.glm summary I obtain:

```
Call:
NULL

Deviance Residuals: 
  Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-5090.0  -1025.5   -208.1    833.4   4948.4  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7771.56      64.93 119.688  < 2e-16 ***
pce          5750.27    1153.03   4.987 8.15e-07 ***
pop         -1483.01    1117.06  -1.328    0.185    
psavert      2932.38     144.56  20.286  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 2420081)

Null deviance: 3999514594  on 573  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1379446256  on 570  degrees of freedom


AIC: 10072

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

The parameters showed refer to the last trained GLM or are "average" paramters?
I hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resampling method is like any others. The RMSE is estimated using different subsets of the training data. Note that it says "`Summary of sample sizes: 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, 168, ...`". The final model uses *all* of the training data set.

The difference between Rob's results and these are primarily due to the difference between Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)